# Using regex to trim URLs?

Tags: regex, shell, command-line, ssh, command

I have a text file that followers this format:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/user1242/random-information
http://www.mywebsite.com/otheruser/writing-other-stuff
http://www.mywebsite.com/anotheruser/fwefawef-wfefwef
http://www.mywebsite.com/testuser/fwefweaf-fawefw
http://www.mywebsite.com/testing123/this-is-a-test
```

I want to trim the last part and make the list look like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/user1242
http://www.mywebsite.com/otheruser
http://www.mywebsite.com/anotheruser
http://www.mywebsite.com/testuser
http://www.mywebsite.com/testing123
```

Is this possible to do with regex or should I be looking for a different way to do it?

I was hoping to do it through command line, but I can run it through something like NotePad++ if that's easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {$NF=""; print substr($0, 1, length($0)-1)}' file
http://www.mywebsite.com/user1242
http://www.mywebsite.com/otheruser
http://www.mywebsite.com/anotheruser
http://www.mywebsite.com/testuser
http://www.mywebsite.com/testing123
```

Comment: Worked perfect!  Thanks!  I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes when it lets me!

Comment: Why play games with length when you could just `NF--` and print?

Comment: @EtanReisner: `NF--` only works with gnu-awk, it doesn't work with other awk like BSD awk on OSX

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
sed 's@/[^/]\+$@@g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk NF-- FS=/ OFS=/
```

Result

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/user1242
http://www.mywebsite.com/otheruser
http://www.mywebsite.com/anotheruser
http://www.mywebsite.com/testuser
http://www.mywebsite.com/testing123
```

Comment: `NF--` only works with gnu-awk, it doesn't work with other awk versions like BSD awk on OSX